# Looking for a recommendation on using .NET and C++ managed vs. natively

Tags: .net, windows, obfuscation

My company is currently in a transition from VB6 programs to .NET. I've been writing modules for the legacy programs as native C++ DLLs for a while now, and my boss envisions a scenario where we basically port the GUI and related logic (what buttons appear when etc.) to VB.NET and keep developing the underlying program logic as native C++ DLLs.

He is rather worried that .NET code might be copied because the intermediate language can be easily and reliably decompiled, quite like Java class files. So please assume that someone really wants his code, but disassembling from native code is infeasable for them.

Now, I kind of think that it would be wiser to just develop everything in .NET, such as managed C++. Then the interface between GUI and program is probably *much* less of a hassle, does not involve COM or other inter-process communications, and I could also use the whole .NET API which I think might save me quite some time coding.

Please tell me if my assumptions are questionable or wrong. If this is correct however and you would also recommend to just program in .NET if it **must** be used for the GUI anyway, what are some good arguments that I can approach my boss with?

I've heard that there are obfuscators. Are they reliable? How hard do they make decompilation? Is there a particularly good one, or also, for testing, a free one you've had good results with? I guess that ensuring him that his codebase is safe is the biggest issue here, but I'm also looking for insights on other aspects of this whole thing.

Comment: Interesting, now I get anti-reverse-engineering ads here :)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there are good obfuscators, although I don't have enough experience with them to say just *how* good they are. I've heard good things about [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview). They do have an evaluation version.

If you're going to write .NET code, I would suggest doing everything that you can in .NET. The only reason I'd write new native code is if I really needed the performance (.NET code will be slower for heavy computation), or if the native code is doing something that you just can't do in .NET. That said, I wouldn't suggest converting your existing native code to .NET if you don't have to. It's pretty easy, using Platform Invoke, to call native code from .NET.

But I would write new code in managed C++, or one of the other managed languages. It makes things easier. In addition, you can leverage the .NET runtime libraries, which will probably save you coding time. You'll be using the same runtime environment as the GUI code, which means that you can use the same data structures that they use. That will simplify coding and reduce the number of problems you have marshaling data between the GUI code and your processing code.